# C language: Children don't exit, nor terminate and are not killed my parent process too

Tags: c, parent-child, children, parents

I can't exit or terminate children processes sending a signal.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this code:

```
//###################################### INVERTER.C (main)   
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "timeprofiler.h"
#include "ppmtools.h"

//Global vars:
int shmids[4], shmPixelId, *total_lines, *processed_lines, *next_line, *buf_vars;
//To share unnamed semaphores between processes, they must be allocated in a shared memory.
mem_struct *sh_mm;
//unnamed semaphores
sem_t *mutex1, *mutex2, *mutex3, *sem_remaining_lines;
//struct that will hold the image in shared memory
image_struct *image;
pid_t *workersPID;
header *h;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, j, k, cur = 0, id;
    pixel *row;
    double start, stop, startms, stopms;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Incorrect usage.\nPlease use \"./invert input_filename.ppm output_filename.ppm\"\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //BLOCK ALL SIGNAL
    sigset_t block_ctrlc;
    sigfillset(&block_ctrlc);
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &block_ctrlc, NULL);

    //start timer
    start = getCurrentTimeMicro();
    startms = getCurrentTimeMili();

    printf("Opening input file [%s]\n", argv[1]);
    FILE *fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fpin == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open input file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Opening output file [%s]\n", argv[2]);
    FILE *fpout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (fpout == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open output file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Getting header\n");
    h = getImageHeader(fpin);
    if (h == NULL) {
        printf("Error getting header from file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Got file Header: %s - %u x %u - %u\n", h->type, h->width, h->height, h->depth);

    printf("Saving header to output file\n");
    if (writeImageHeader(h, fpout) == -1) {
        printf("Could not write to output file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    init();
    printf("After init...\n");
    //alloc mem space for one row (width * size of one pixel struct)
    row = (pixel *) malloc(h->width * sizeof (pixel));

    printf("Starting work\n");
    for (i = 0; i < h->height; i++) {
        printf("Reading row... \n");
        if (getImageRow(h->width, row, fpin) == -1) {
            printf("Error while reading row\n");
        }
        printf("Got row %d || \n", (i + 1));
        for (j = cur, k = 0; j < cur + h->width; j++, k++) {
            image->pixel_data[j].red = row[k].red;
            image->pixel_data[j].blue = row[k].blue;
            image->pixel_data[j].green = row[k].green;
        }
        cur += h->width;
    }

    /*Creates workers*/
    workersPID = (pid_t*) malloc(sizeof (pid_t) *((NUM_WORKERS)));
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
        id = fork();
        if (id == -1) {
            printf("Error creating worker no %d\n", i);
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (id == 0) {
            workersPID[i] = getpid();
            printf("Launching son with pid %d\n", getpid());
            worker(i);
        }
    }
    cur = 0;
    sem_wait(mutex2);

    /*Writes the invert image on the output file*/
    for (i = 0; i < h->height; i++) {
        for (j = cur, k = 0; j < cur + h->width; j++, k++) {
            row[k].red = image->pixel_data[j].red;
            row[k].blue = image->pixel_data[j].blue;
            row[k].green = image->pixel_data[j].green;
        }
        cur += h->width;
        printf("Saving row... \n");
        if (writeRow(h->width, row, fpout) == -1) {
            printf("Error while writing row\n");
        }
        printf("Done\n");
    }

    printf("Cleaning up...\n");
    //clean up row
    free(row);
    //clean up header
    free(h);

    printf("Closing file pointers.\n");
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
    //stop timer
    stop = getCurrentTimeMicro();
    stopms = getCurrentTimeMili();

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++) {
        if (workersPID[i]) {
            kill(workersPID[i], SIGTERM); 
            waitpid(workersPID[i], NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    terminate();
    printTimeElapsed(start, stop, "microseconds");
    printTimeElapsed(startms, stopms, "miliseconds");
    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}

void init() {

    //create shared memory to hold the source image:
    if ((shmids[0] = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof (image_struct), IPC_CREAT | 0700)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget to allocate image struct failed. Errno returned:  %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    image = (image_struct*) shmat(shmids[0], NULL, 0);

    //shared memory to allocate the pointer to pointer pixel_data
    if ((shmids[1] = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, h->width * h->height * sizeof (pixel), IPC_CREAT | 0700)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget to allocate pixel_data array failed. Errno returned: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    image->pixel_data = (pixel*) shmat(shmids[1], NULL, 0);

    /*Shared Memory segment for 3 integers*/
    if ((shmids[2] = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3 * sizeof (int), IPC_CREAT | 0700)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget to allocate the 3 integers failed. Errno returned;  %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buf_vars = (int*) shmat(shmids[2], NULL, 0);
    total_lines = &buf_vars[0];
    processed_lines = &buf_vars[1];
    next_line = &buf_vars[2];

    *processed_lines = *next_line = 0;
    *total_lines = h->height;

    if ((shmids[3] = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof (mem_struct), IPC_CREAT | 0700)) == -1) {
        printf("shmget to allocate mem_Struct for semaphores failed. Errno returned %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sh_mm = (mem_struct*) shmat(shmids[3], NULL, 0);
    if (sem_init(&sh_mm->mutex1, 1, 1) == -1) {
        printf("Error initializing semaphore mutex1.Errno returned: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    mutex1 = &sh_mm->mutex1;

    if (sem_init(&sh_mm->mutex2, 1, 0) == -1) {
        printf("Error initializing semaphore mutex2.Errno returned: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    mutex2 = &sh_mm->mutex2;

    if (sem_init(&sh_mm->mutex3, 1, 1) == -1) {
        printf("Error initializing semaphore mutex3.Errno returned: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    mutex3 = &sh_mm->mutex3;

    if (sem_init(&sh_mm->sem_remaining_lines, 1, h->height) == -1) {
        printf("Error initializing semaphore sem_remaining_lines.Errno returned: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sem_remaining_lines = &sh_mm->sem_remaining_lines;
}

/*Worker process*/
void worker(int id) {
    int i, k, cur = 0;
    pixel *row;
    //Block all signals, except SIGINT and SIGKILL which are handled
    sigset_t block_ctrlc;
    sigfillset(&block_ctrlc);
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGTERM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &block_ctrlc, NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);
    while (sem_wait(sem_remaining_lines)!= -1) { //if there are still lines to read, go on
        sem_wait(mutex3);
        cur = *next_line; //current image's line
        *next_line += h->width; //refreshs line for the next worker
        sem_post(mutex3);
        row = (pixel *) malloc(h->width * sizeof (pixel));
        for (i = cur, k = 0; i < cur + h->width; i++, k++) {
            row[k].red = image->pixel_data[i].red;
            row[k].blue = image->pixel_data[i].blue;
            row[k].green = image->pixel_data[i].green;
        }
        //printf("% - Inverting row... \n",id);
        invertRow(h->width, row); //invert 
        //printf("Done || \n");
        for (i = cur, k = 0; i < cur + h->width; i++, k++) {
            image->pixel_data[i].red = row[k].red;
            image->pixel_data[i].blue = row[k].blue;
            image->pixel_data[i].green = row[k].green;
        }
        sem_wait(mutex1);
        *processed_lines += 1; //increases the number of inverted lines
        if (*processed_lines == *total_lines) { //check if it reaches last line
            sem_post(mutex2); //if so, wakes the master telling that is ready
        }
        sem_post(mutex1);
    }
    //printf("Son %d is exiting\n",id);
    exit(0);
}

void handle_signal(int signum) {
    if(signum == SIGINT)
        signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    else
        signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);
    exit(0);
}

void terminate() {
    int i;
    //close semaphores
    sem_destroy(mutex1);
    sem_destroy(mutex2);
    sem_destroy(mutex3);
    sem_destroy(sem_remaining_lines);

    //cleans up shared memory = removes shared memory segments
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        shmctl(shmids[i], IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }

}
```

I'm gonna leave the explanation of the assignment (that has already finished btw)here:
[1 page pdf](http://www.easy-share.com/1913085629/os_proj#2_page3.pdf)

Comment: At least tell us 1) what you expect/want, and 2) what's actually happening.

Comment: My ppm image is in shared memory and each child has to invert it. When there are no more lines to invert,i.e., when you can't decrement sem_ramining_lines, child exits and the others should too, or at least the father could be able to do so, but it's not happening neither of them. They never reach the exit(0) call in the worker() function and the parent isn't able to kill them sending a signal, nor wait for them. The father knows the inversion is completed when a worker does post on sem_mutex2, in which the father waits, after doing forks.

Comment: I can only imagine what a non-programmer would think of you when looking at a question with a title like this, lol.

Comment: The output is great, everything's fine, except the NUM_WORKERS are still alive (when I do ps aux I can see them. Btw, how can I see only the zombie processes or the orphan ones?) . I always do the kill and/or waitpid after the for that spawns children, but it seems that this approach is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your worker threads have `SIGTERM` blocked (because it was blocked in `main`, and `sigprocmask` doesn't remove signals from the blocked set unless explicitly told to do so)

You may want to do something like this in the worker instead:

```
sigemptyset(&block_ctrlc);
sigaddset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
sigaddset(&block_ctrlc, SIGTERM);
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &block_ctrlc, NULL);
```

Alternately, call `sigprocmask` with `SIG_SETMASK`.

Comment: but //BLOCK ALL SIGNAL
    sigset_t block_ctrlc;
    sigfillset(&block_ctrlc);
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &block_ctrlc, NULL); doesn't this mean that we are filling the set with ALL signs, removing the SIGINT and tell it to block the whole set, except sigint? In the main code ...

Comment: They still alive with that changes...unless I haven't understood right. I did in the parent: //BLOCK ALL SIGNAL
    sigset_t block_ctrlc;
    sigfillset(&block_ctrlc);  and in children: sigemptyset(&block_ctrlc);
    sigaddset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&block_ctrlc, SIGTERM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &block_ctrlc, NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal)
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGINT);
    sigdelset(&block_ctrlc, SIGTERM);

Comment: Use of `sigprocmask` in a multithreaded program has either unspecified or undefined behavior; I forget which. Use `pthread_sigmask`.

Comment: @R: Not an issue here, since he's using `fork`. It's multi-process.